# VSTS CD stage task always prints log in one go

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task

I would like to execute UI test cases as as part of CI/CD pipeline. I am using VSTS release management. I created a stage & run the command (npm run e2e-run) as part of one of the tasks, this triggers my test case execution. It takes around 1 hour to execute this task.

Problem is I do not get any response until whole task (test execution) is done. I get only this message "Waiting for console output from an agent...". If I execute command locally in VS code then I get continuous logs (pass/fail messages).

I am observing same behaviour with other tasks as well. Can anybody please tell me how can I get logs continuously instead in one go.

Comment: Check this: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/326645/waiting-for-console-output-from-an-agent-on-releas.html

Comment: Already checked, I do not get logs even after refreshing the page or pressing the "Refresh" button.Logs comes after completion of task only..

Comment: Press F12 on the browser, are you seeing any errors in the console? and which URL format do you use to access your acounts...? *.visualstudio.com?